# can we get different navigation bars corresponding different navigation  controllers in iOS?

Tags: ios5, xcode4, uinavigationbar, background-image, viewcontroller

i am new in app. I wanted to display customize navigation bar background images. Actually i read '`setBackgroundImage: forBarMetrics:`' for `UINavigationBar`. I wanted to apply this different navigation controllers and then the result will be getting different navigation bars. I don't get like that i get only one navigation bar for all view controllers.

Can we get different navigation bars corresponding different navigation controllers in the same app? or any other way is there? Please tell me. Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The navigation bar doesn't belong to the view controllers; it belongs to the navigation controller. It isn't "one navigation bar for all view controllers", it's one navigation bar for the one navigation controller.

If you want to change dynamically the way it looks, respond to the navigation controller's delegate messages telling you when the view controller changes.

Comment: Oh... Thank you for suggesting me. May i know what the procedure is? Please explain to me